# can we have two controls (grid control and a chart control) on the same space/real estate

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a simple .aspx page (attached in the post).

I want to show the data either in Chart control or Gridview control. When the user selects an option to see the data either in chart control or grid view control, that specific control has to show up and other control has to become invisible.

So far, I am able to populate data succcessfully in the chart control. If the user chooses "Grid view" option, how can I show the data in grid view control in the same location. I don't want the gridview control to be shown in a pop up window or any other window.

any suggestions please

Comment: `"attached in the post"`?  Without seeing any code it's difficult to say for certain, but it sounds like you just want to show/hide page elements dynamically.  This is easily done with JavaScript and CSS.  With jQuery you'd just call `.hide()` or `.show()` on those elements (or any number of other versions thereof, toggling or animating accordingly).  They don't necessarily "occupy the same space" they just dynamically show/hide on the page and the browser renders the flow of the page as needed.

Comment: What is it that the user is using to select between a chart and grid view. Are you trying to do it with radio buttons, or a dropdown maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a multiview control?

I haven't seen any of your code, but say you have a button for the chart and a button for the gridview,  you would just change the view being shown within the multiview in the button.click event.

Comment: you can manually enter 4 spaces before each line, or there are controls above the text area that you are typing (unless you are in a comment).

Comment: If this fixed your issue, do you think there is any way that you can mark it as the correct answer? It would be greatly appreciated. :)